# How to setup github login to push file using cmd

Tags: github

I have setup my github using the global command, but when I try to push my file it request this commands:

`git remote add <name> <url>` and then push using the remote name `git push <name>`

When I carefully follow the command it requests for this command:

To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use `git push --set-upstream gh-pages master`

I typed in the command, then I was asked for username which I typed now the next input which is the password, the command line failed to effect the insertion point.

Comment: You just need to type the correct password, it will accept it. It won't show what are you typing.